# How to get keys and sub keys from the array of object?

Tags: javascript, arrays, dictionary, object

I have below array of objects.

```
const array = [{
  field1: "val1",
  field2: "val2",
  field3: {
    field1: "val1",
    field2: "val2"
  }
},
{
  field1: "val1",
  field2: "val2",
  field3: {
    field1: "val1"
  }
}]
```

I need to get below output

```
const output = [{
  key: "field1",
  subkeys: []
},
{
  key: "field2",
  subkeys: []
},
{
  key: "field3",
  subkeys: ["field1", "field2"]
}]
```

I can get the top level field using this

```
const keys = array.map(x => Object.keys(x)[0]);
```

But not able to access the inner ones.

Kindly help... Thanks!!!

Comment: do you have only two levels of objects?

Comment: @DarkKnight: is your expected output

`const output = [[{key: "field1", subkeys: [] }, {key: "field2", subkeys: [] }, {key: "field3", subkeys: ["field1", "field2"] }], [{key: "field1", subkeys: [] }, {key: "field2", subkeys: [] }, {key: "field3", subkeys: ["field1"] }]]`

That is, an array of arrays? Or the one mentioned in the question

Comment: @DhivyaDandapani As mentioned in the question. Not an array of array

Comment: @DarkKnight: Thank you. But the answers that have been picked so far don't seem to return the expected answer. Are you still looking for the accurate answer?

Comment: @DarkKnight: Could you please post a sample input-output for multi-level nested json also? I posted an answer. I could modify it based on your requirement

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can reduce an array of Object keys on the top level and then check if value for this key is object - retrieve its nested keys, otherwise just leave the empty array of subkeys

```js
const array = [{
  field1: "val1",
  field2: "val2",
  field3: {
    field1: "val1",
    field2: "val2"
  }
},
{
  field1: "val1",
  field2: "val2",
  field3: {
    field1: "val1"
  }
}]

const result = array.map(item => {
  return Object.keys(item).reduce((acc, rec) => {
    if(typeof item[rec] === 'object') {
      return [...acc, {key: rec, subkeys: Object.keys(item[rec])}] 
    }
    return [...acc, {key: rec, subkeys: []}]
  }, [])
})

console.log(result)
```

Comment: Just a small question... Can It be done for unknown level ?

Comment: @DarkKnight for unknown level function should be recursive. reduce should be written as a function and in the condition when typeof new child is object - just run recursion

Comment: Be aware of the [reduce ({...spread}) anti-pattern](https://www.richsnapp.com/article/2019/06-09-reduce-spread-anti-pattern)

Answer (score 2):

You could map for any depth by looking to nested objects.

```js
const
    getKeys = object => Object.keys(object).map(key => ({ 
        key, 
        subkeys: object[key] && typeof object[key] === 'object'
            ? getKeys(object[key])
            : []
    })),
    array = [{ field1: "val1", field2: "val2", field3: { field1: "val1", field2: "val2" } }, { field1: "val1", field2: "val2", field3: { field1: "val1" } }];

console.log(array.map(getKeys));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 2):

This solution uses the **lodash** library. I have extracted the variables for better readability. This solution will work for 2 levels

```
const array = [
    {"field1":"val1","field2":"val2","field3":{"field1":"val1","field2":"val2"}},
    {"field1":"val1","field2":"val2","field3":{"field1":"val1","field4":"val1"}}
];

intermediateOutput = array.reduce(
  (accumulator, entry) => _.merge(accumulator, entry),
{});
// intermediateOutput = {"field1":"val1","field2":"val2","field3":{"field1":"val1","field2":"val2","field4":"val1"}}

const finalOutput = _.map(_.keys(intermediateOutput), (key) => {
  const value = intermediateOutput[key];
  return {key, subkeys: _.isObject(value) ? _.keys(value): [] }
})

console.log(finalOutput);
// finalOutput = [{"key":"field1","subkeys":[]},{"key":"field2","subkeys":[]},{"key":"field3","subkeys":["field1","field2","field4"]}]
```

Comment: Actually I have this array of object https://lodashfiddle.herokuapp.com/ka6dpidr/.... I need  this keys as it is, but with blank string.

Comment: @DarkKnight: Thanks for the lodashfiddle. The array posted in the fiddle doesn't seem to be well formed. Also, it would help if you also mention the expected output for the array posted in the lodashfiddle as a comment.

Answer (score 1):

```
const output = []
for (let [key, value] of Object.entries(array)) {
    const subkeys = Object.keys(value)
    output.push({key, subkeys})
}
```

Something like that?